# Flex HAccordion No Text?

Tags: apache-flex

I'm a flex noob and I'm trying to figure out how to implement a horizontal accordion.  I'm trying to make a horizontal version of the accordion on Doug McCune's blog: http://dougmccune.com/blog/2007/09/22/nifty-flex-accordion-menu-like-on-applecom/

I'm simply switching VAccordion to HAccordion (and some styling), when I do that, text no longer renders on the headers. I can add other components to the headers, and those will render, but not text.

How do I make text appear on the headers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until the release of version 10, Flash Player had a limitation where rotated text could not be displayed with standard device fonts. If you are targeting Flash Player 9, you need to [embed the font](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/fonts_04.html) used in the headers. The default font, by the way, is Verdana.